# Comparator power dissipation

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, design, comparator, hardware

I want to calculate the LM339 comparator power efficiency, so I thought the best way is to calculate the output RMS power and the Power dissipation and the quiescent(DC) power then will get the input power.
then Eff=Po/Pin
but I have a problem in calculating the DC power? 
I'm i doing it right? and how to calculate the quiescent power for the comoparator as there is no Iq in datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

Figure 1 in the data sheet: -

[image]

It also says 0.8 mA on page 1.

The better option would be to use a DC (average) milli ammeter.